# A $k$-dimensional reduced subscheme $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $1$ is a linearly embedded $k$-plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-schemes

In following all schemes $X$
will be considered as separated, of finite type over
an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic $0$.
Recall that a *Hilbert function* $HF_S: \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0$ associates to a
finitely generated graded commutative algebra $S= \bigoplus_{i \ge 0} S_i$
over a field $K$, which is finitely generated by elements of positive degree
the value

$$ HF_S(n) := \dim_k S_n    $$

(the $k$-dimension of $n$-graded piece). One can show that there exist
a unique polynomial $P_S(t) \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ and
a $n_0(S) \in \mathbb{N}$, which depends on $S$, such that for all $n \ge n_0(S)$
we have

$$  HF_S(n) = P_S(n)   $$

This $P_S$ is unique and called the Hilbert polynomial of $S$.
Consider following proposition and proof from "3264 & All That" by Eisenbud & Harris (p 204):

> **Proposition 6.7.** A subscheme $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a linearly embedded
> $k$-plane (ie isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^k$) if and only
> if the Hilbert polynomial of $Y$ is

$$  P(d) = \binom{d+k}{k} = \frac{(d+k)(d+k-1)... (d+1)}{k(k-1)...1} $$

> **Proof:** Since the dimension of the $d$-th graded component of a polynomial
> ring on $k+1$ variables is $\binom{d+k}{k} $, the Hilbert polynomial of a
> linearly embedded $k$-plane is $P(d)$.
> Conversely, suppose that $Y$ has Hilbert polynomial $P$. From the degree and leading
> coefficient of $P$ we see that $Y$ is a scheme of dimension $k$ and degree $1$. Thus
> $L :=Y_{red} \to Y$ is a linearly embedded $k$-plane. (why?)
> This inclusion induces a surjection of
> homogeneous coordinate rings $S_Y \to S_L$, and the equality of Hilbert polynomials shows
> that it is an isomorphism in high degrees. Since the inclusions
> $L \subset Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ can be
> recovered as
> $\operatorname{Proj}(S_L) \subset \operatorname{Proj}(S_Y) \subset \operatorname{Proj}(S) =
> \mathbb{P}^n$, where $S=K[x_0,..., x_n]$ is the homogeneous coordinate
> ring of $\mathbb{P}^n$, and since $\operatorname{Proj}(S_Y)$ depends only on the high degree
> part of $S_Y$ , this shows $L \subset Y$ is actually an equality.

Question: Why it's immediate clear that $Y_{red}$ is a linearly embedded $k$-plane? Or
equivalently, that a reduced $k$-dimensional subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
of degree $1$ isomorphic to a $k$-plane $\mathbb{P}^k$? So the proof suggests that *reducedness* is the key point here making the latter statement "trivial". Any ideas which arguments the authors use here?

My ideas: We know that Hilbert functions and therefore Hilbert polynomials are additive
with respect exact sequences. The homogeneous coordinate rings of $Y$ and
$Y_{red} $ are related by following exact sequence of homogeneous $S_Y$-modules:

$$   0 \to \mathcal{Nil}(S_Y) \to S_Y \to S_Y/(\mathcal{Nil}(S_Y)) = S_{Y_{red}} \to 0   $$

Therefore $P_{S_Y}= P_{Y_{red}}+P_{\mathcal{Nil}(S_Y)}$. Do we know here more about
$P_{\mathcal{Nil}(S_Y)}$? Since $\dim(Y) = \dim(Y_{red})$ and the dimension of
the scheme equals to the degree of the associated Hilbert
polynomial to it's coordinate ring, $P_{Y}$ and $P_{Y_{red}}$ have same degrees.

It is known that the leading coefficient $a_k$ of the Hilbert polynomial $P_X$ of a $k$-dimensional
subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d = \operatorname{deg}(X)$ equals $a_k = \frac{d}{k!}$.
The *degree* is a positive integer, so the lowest possible value which a leading coefficient
of a Hilbert polynomial could have is $\frac{1}{k!}$ and $P_{Y}$ has this coefficent.
Therefore $P_{Y_{red}} $ and $P_{\mathcal{Nil}(S_Y)}$ cannot simultaneosly have degree $k$.
But $\dim(Y) = \dim(Y_{red})$, so $P_{Y_{red}} $ has degree $k$, and it's
leading coefficient coincides with $\frac{1}{k!}$, the leading coefficient of $P_{S_Y}$.
Furthermore, since
the degree of $Y$ equals to $a_n \cdot n!$, where $a_n$ is the leading coefficient
of  $P_{S_Y}$, as the proof states we have that $ Y_{red}$ has the the same degree as $Y$, namely $1$.

Why this implies that $Y_{red}$ is is a linearly embedded $k$-plane? What we
can easily deduce is that if $Y_{red}$ decomposes as $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup ... \sup X_m$
in irreducible components then there is only one $X_i$ with $\dim X_i= \dim Y_{red}$,
again because of additivity of Hilbert polynomial $P_{Y_{red}}=
P_{X_1} + P_{X_2} + ... + P_{X_m}$, fact that the leading coefficient of Hilbert
polynomial is always positive and that $P_{Y_{red}}$ has the lowest possible leading coefficient $\frac{1}{k!}$ by considerations above.

Assume now wlog $X_i=X_1$. Since $Y_{red}$ reduced, $X_i$ is reduced and irreducible, therefore integral. Conjecture:  $Y_{red} = X_1$.
So the original problem becomes: Why is an integral (reduced, irreducible) $k$-dimensional subscheme
$X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $1$ isomorphic to a $k$-plane $\mathbb{P}^k$?

Comment: Closed subscheme? The claim seems elementary to me, that $K[x_{e_0},\ldots,x_{e_k}]\to S$ is a surjection and an isomorphism by comparing the dimensions of the graded pieces, where $x_{e_0},\ldots,x_{e_k}$ is a basis of $S(1)$

Comment: @reuns: Althought the authors haven't mentioned it explicitely I assume that they mean indeed closed subscheme.

Comment: I'm not sure if your argument works like this. The are two problems: 
the first one is that *Hilbert polynomial* not coincides with 
*Hilbert function* in all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but only in "big enough"
values. ie there exist a $n_0(S_Y) \in \mathbb{N}$ depending on 
$S_Y$, such that for all $n \ge n_0$ the values
$P_{S_Y}(n) = HF_{S_Y}(n) = HF_{S_Y}(n) := \dim_K (S_Y)_n$ coinside. So there 
is no reason why should this be the case for low numbers, ie $n=1$.
So in our case there is no reason why $\dim_K (S_Y)_1 = 
\binom{k+1}{k} (= \dim_K K[x_0,..., x_k]_1)$ should hold.

Comment: Ah sorry, thank you, I missed that you meant $\dim S(d)={k+d\choose k}$ only for $d$ large enough. Yes much less elementary because of this.

Comment: The result is clear if $k=n-1$, so it is enough to show that an integral $k$-subscheme ($k <n$) of degree $1$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is *contained* in a proper hyperplane. Maybe using the geometric properties of degree this is not difficult. Just an idea

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez: So you suggest an inductive argument as far as we 
know that $Y_{red}$ is contained in a proper hyperplane, right?

Comment: As far as I see one can show that an integral $k$-subscheme
$X$ of degree $1$ contained in a hyperplane as follows: Fix a sufficiently general $(n-1)$-hyperplane $H^{n-1}$  intersecting $X$ in a degree 
$1$ and $(k-1)$-dimensional
variety $X \cap H^{n-1}$.

Comment: Then it's obvious that 
a general $(n-k)$-plane $H^{n-k}$ choosen in that way that intersecting $X$ in 
a point $ H^{n-k} \cap X= \{x\} \not \in H^{n-1}$ (that's important!) intersects
with $H^{n-1}$ in a $(n-k-1)$-plane $H^{n-k-1}:=H^{n-1} \cap H^{n-k}$.
Since we have choosen $H^{n-1}$ such that $X \cap H^{n-1}$ has 
degree $1$ and $H^{n-k-1}$ is general, the intersection
$H^{n-k-1} \cap X = H^{n-1} \cap H^{n-k} \cap X = \{y\} \in H^{n-1}$.
That's absurd because by choice of general $H^{n-k}$ we have
$H^{n-k} \cap X = \{x\} \not \in H^{n-1} $

Comment: @katalaveino yes, that is exaclty what I meant.

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez: by the way: I just noticed that my "argument" above that 
irred degree $1$ subscheme $X$ is contained in 
a hyperplane not works that way, because 
intersecting $X \cap H^{n-1}$ with 
$H^{n-k-1}:=H^{n-1} \cap H^{n-k}$ for general
$H^{n-k}$ is sincerly empty by dimensional reasons.
(I missed in my "proof" the dimension shift)

Comment: But I think meanwhile that for irreducible $X^k$ of degree $1$
it's easier to show directly that it's linear instead
of the intermediate step that it is contained in 
a hyperplane. It suffice to show that for 
every pair $x_1 \neq x_2 \in X$ the line $L$ spanned
by them is contained in $X$. Assume, that's not the 
case. Then $\#(L \cap X)$ is finite $\ge 2$. 
Then enlarge $L$ to a $(n-k)$-plane $H^{(n-k)}$
which contains $L$ and intersects $X$ properly, ie 
$H^{(n-k)} \cap X= \{a_1,..., a_s\}$ finite.
Therefore $\deg(X) \ge s \ge 2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nonetheless, out of curiosity, do you see an 
elementary argument to show 
that a $k$-dimensional subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ 
of degree $1$ is contained in a hyperplane 
directly? Although the statement looks rather
weaker than the original claim above, I didn't manage to find 
a direct argument without taking the detour 
presented in my previous comment.